# How Add-Migration compare current model to find the differences?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm learning to use EF Code First Migrations from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx

Somewhere it said:

> Code First Migrations has two primary commands that you are going to
> become familiar with.
>
> **Add-Migration** will scaffold the next migration based on changes you
> have made to your model *since the last migration was created*.
>
> **Update-Database** will apply any pending migrations to the database.

I don't understand what's **Add-Migration** doing exactly. To more precise, my problem is with:

> since the last migration was created

In order to create a migration, it should pick two *database structure* to compare.

Obviously, one side is the *current structure of models in the code*. But what is the other side? The options are:

1. Populating a database structure by unifying all migrations from initial to the last migration before this?
2. Comparing it to a database which has the old structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the code behind files of your migrations - they contain a lot of metadata, including a snapshot of the model from when it was created.

So, when you run `Add-Migration` the process is approximately this:

1. Build a model based on your code
2. Find the previous model from your last migration (if applicable)
3. Compare the two models
4. Generate a migration based on the difference

There's a [useful article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn481501.aspx) with some information and videos that cover this in more detail.